# Android - disable button while thread is running

Tags: android, multithreading, button, background

SO, i basically want to disable a button until a thread that handles some downloads is finished, how do i approach this in the best way? at first I thought of a quick fix:

```
while(thread.alive())
{
button.disable();
}
```

I don't feel like this is a good way of solving this problem, Also i cant use the "AsyncTask" solution since the operation is going to handle pretty large files over slow connections. Is the proper approach to use a listener?

Edit: My question is not about what function to use in order to disable the button, but rather about how I know when the thread is finished and how I can keep the button disabled until the thread is finished.

Comment: you may use button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is easy: disable the button in `onClicked`

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

This will provide proper feedback to the user.

The second part can be handled in many ways. You will need callback of some sorts in most of them.

- If you are using an `AsyncTask` you should enable the button again in `onPostExecute`.
- Callbacks with libraries like `Retrofit` or `Volley` would also just enable the button again on finish.
- If you use `DownloadManager` you can and should listen for the broadcasts sent. You would need to store the `id` of the download to identify your files though.

All in all you need to provide methods of feedback and need to ensure that the callbacks *are* triggered, so that the button will not stay in its disabled state.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
button.setClickable(false);
```

rather than

```
button.disable();
```